# How to convert datetime to date datatype while joining in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, casting

I am trying to join two datasets together while changing a datatype that will appear in the output.

When I run the following, the join processes, but I have not converted my datetime columns to date columns:

```
SELECT  *
FROM [DATABASE].[table1]
     LEFT JOIN [DATABASE].[View] ON DATABASE.Column6=View.Column7
```

Below is my attempt to fix my date columns with `CAST()`
When I run this, trying to fix my datetime issue, by being explicit, the join does not work:

```
SELECT [Table1].[Column1] as 'c1',
       [Table1].[Column2] as 'c2',
       [Table1].[Column3] as 'c3',
       [Table1].[Column4] as 'c4',
       [Table1].[Column5] as 'c5',
       [Table1].[Column6] as 'c6',
       CAST([Table1].[Start_Date] AS Date) AS 'Start_Date',
       CAST([Table1].[End_Date] AS Date) AS 'End_Date',
       [Table1].[Column7] as 'c7',
       [Table1].[Column8] as 'c8',
       [Table1].[Column9] as 'c9'
FROM [DATABASE].[Table1]
      LEFT JOIN [DATABASE].[View] ON Table1.Column6=View.Column7
```

Does anyone understand why this would be? I would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: `ON DATABASE.Column6=View.Column7` will produce an error, there is no object named/aliased `DATABASE` in that query.

Comment: Do you *really* have a schema called `DATABASE`? That is a poor choice of name if so.

Comment: I just put that in for this example. The first query does not return an error and has almost the expected output. The second does not produce an error but does not join the data.

Comment: You're casting the data in the SELECT, which happens AFTER the JOINs. So, include the CAST in the JOIN itself. `a LEFT JOIN b ON a.foo = CAST(b.bar AS DATE)`

Comment: Thank you! It isn't one of the columns on which I join though?

Comment: Why do you have a `LEFT JOIN` to the object `[DATABASE].[View]` anyway? In the second query, you don't return *any* of the columns in the `SELECT`.

Comment: Side note, don't use single quotes (`'`) for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. They only work when you define them, no where else; `ORDER BY 'value'` would *not* order by your column aliased as `'value'`, it would order by the `varchar` literal `'value'` (so would effectively not order at all). Also some syntaxes with literal string aliases are deprecated. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you *must* delimit identify them use the T-SQL identifier, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (`"`).

Comment: Hi Larnu, all I am returning in the second query are the columns in the ```SELECT```.

Comment: Hi Larnu, thank you for this advice. I'll look into it to clean up my query going forward.

Comment: CASTing the data as part of the SELECT list will not affect the success or failure of the JOIN.  In the SELECT list, your are simply declaring what you want the selected columns to look like..

Comment: The queries should be identical except for the ```CAST()``` though.